# Add number to range based on ratio

Tags: excel, vba

For backstory, trying to add a flat fee to a subtotal of fees (Y17:Y46) based on each subtotal's ratio to the total fee. Have tried with little success. Any help would be appreciated. Flatreffee and Total have been assigned a value previously in the macro.

```
Sub Flat_Fee()
'Adds in the flat referral fee, if it's a number
Dim cell As Range
Dim total As Integer
    For Each cell In Range("Y17:Y46").Select
        If IsNumeric(flatreffee) And cell.Value > 0 Then
            cell = cell + (cell / total) * flatreffee
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `total` has not been assigned a value, nor has `flatreffee`. `(cell / total)` is division by 0 currently.

Comment: Apologies, i should have noted that flatreffee and total have been assigned a value previously in the macro.

Comment: That's why your question should be a [reprex]. And you should be specific about what isn't working. We shouldn't have to guess about code we can't see. We shouldn't have to guess what isn't working. Please also see [ask] and maybe take the [tour].

Comment: @BigBen Will do

Comment: If you had declared `total` and assigned the value somewhere else properly then it would not have allowed to re declare it inside the sub.  My guess is that you think they are declared and assigned but they are not being passed to this sub correctly.  Right now the only answer we can give is that `total` is `0` when this is run.  You will need to step through line by line and check the value of each variable to ensure it is what you think it should.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that makes sense. Appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
' After first hard-coding total and flatrefee 
' and **removing ".Select"** this worked for me.
Sub Flat_Fee()
'Adds in the flat referral fee, if it's a number
Dim cell As Range
Dim total As Integer
    For Each cell In Range("Y17:Y46")
        If IsNumeric(flatreffee) And cell.Value > 0 Then
            cell = cell + (cell / total) * flatreffee
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help!